# Fragment's state is not being retained

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am calling fragment's onSaveInstance() method in which I have saved the value of edittext and checbox in bundle. In onCreateView I am setting those values to my edittext and checkbox but when I run the app and write something in edittext and rotate my device it becomes blank! can anyone help?

public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

```
public EditText ed;
public CheckBox cb;

public BlankFragment() { }

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    ed = v.findViewById(R.id.edit);
    cb = v.findViewById(R.id.check);
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        ed.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("string"));
        cb.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("bool"));
    }
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("string",ed.getText().toString());
    outState.putBoolean("bool",cb.isChecked());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

}

I have logged those setText and setChecked lines, it prints correct values in log but then why it is not setting anything on views!

Comment: Is the problem in bundle not setting and retrieving correctly or is the problem with the settext and setchecked?

Comment: Problem is with settext and setchecked